# Simplification of 68/95/99.7 rule in normal distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

I recently came across the following formula referenced in this particular answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/493434/106050.

This is pretty much perfect to what I would like to use in a statistical library I'm working on, but I was wondering if there is a way to simplify this such that `f(x)` would yield the decimal percentage of the population covered by `x` standard deviations within a normal distribution; i.e.

```
f(1) = .6827
f(2) = .9545
f(3) = .9973, etc...
```

I'd like this to work for decimal standard deviations as well... what's the simplest equation that could satisfy this? I'm hoping it won't require integral calculation of any kind...

Comment: If you're wanting the exact [cumulative normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function) without an integral you're out of luck - it is an integral without a known elementary equation.

Comment: Note that many programming languages include the error function in their math libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it does require integration.

A normal distribution can be modeled as

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}.$$

So, the probability that a point lies in the range $(-t\sigma+\mu, t\sigma+\mu)$ is

$$\int_{-t\sigma+\mu}^{t\sigma+\mu} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} dx = \int_{-t}^t \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}} dy.$$

This can be expressed in terms of the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), but cannot be written in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: From what I recall in integration the 1/sqrt(2pi) can be moved out, leaving the exponent term... but from memory, doesn't the rest of the integral yield, in turn, 2 * erf(t/sqrt(2))? I'm guessing that can't be simplified, given what I've just read in the Wikipedia entry you've supplied...

Comment: It's possible to prove formally that $\operatorname{erf}$ doesn't have a closed-form representation.